# ms graph php sdk set from name when sending email

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api

Working off of the 'Send and email' example:

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php/wiki/Example-calls#send-an-email

I'm trying to set the 'from name' of the email in the header of the sent email to show 'TEST' instead of the name associated with my OWA account.

```
    $graph = new Graph();
    $graph->setAccessToken(access_token);

    $mailBody = array( "Message" => array(
            "subject" => $subject . ' ' . $from_name,
            "body" => array(
                "contentType" => "html",
                "content" => $body
            ),
            "sender" => array(
                "emailAddress" => array(
                    "name" => "TEST",
                    "address" => $from_user->email
                )
            ),
            "from" => array(
                "emailAddress" => array(
                    "name" => 'TEST',
                    "address" => $from_user->email
                )
            ),
            "toRecipients" => array(
                array(
                    "emailAddress" => array(
                        "name" => $to_user->name,
                        "address" => $to_user->email

                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );

    $response = $graph->createRequest("POST", "/me/sendMail")
        ->attachBody($mailBody)
        ->execute();
```

But the message header always has the name from my OWA (outlook) account instead.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK it is not supported to override `name` property of [`emailAddress` resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/emailaddress?view=graph-rest-1.0) via `senMail` endpoint.

**But** Microsoft Graph supports the feature which allows a user to send mail that appears to be sent from another user, distribution list, group, resource, or shared mailbox ([official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-send-mail-from-other-user#send-as))

Two mailbox permissions affect how a message is sent:

- [Send on Behalf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-send-mail-from-other-user#send-on-behalf)
- [Send As](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-send-mail-from-other-user#send-as)

---

Below is demonstrated on how to sent mail from [distribution group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/recipients-in-exchange-online/manage-distribution-groups/manage-distribution-groups) called `Finance Department`

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/sendMail

{
  "message": {
    "subject": "Finance results",
    "body": {
      "contentType": "text",
      "content": "Some finance results goes here..."
    },
    "toRecipients": [
      {
        "emailAddress": {
          "address": "mary@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
        }
      }
    ],
    "from": {
      "emailAddress": {
        "address": "financedeplist@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Current user: `Jon Doe (jdoe@contoso.onmicrosoft.com)`

**Option 1. Send on Behalf**

[image: Distribution group settings]

[image: Result]

**Option 2. Send As**

[image: Distribution group settings]

[image: Result]